How can I switch mains-powered loads wirelessly, with low cost and low power consumption
I'm setting up a Pi (currently developing on a a 3B, but I'm assuming I'll upgrade to a 4B)  as a CCTV server and fileserver, but I've also just got solar panels installed and would like to switch some loads on when I've got surplus power.  Call it up to 1kW/5A (mains is 240V for me).
I have some experience of designing and building mains-powered kit. If the load was next to the Pi, it would be easy: I'd put one or more opto-isolated solid state relays in a mains-suitable box, driving them off GPIOs (the datasheets I've looked at could be driven directly; other might ned an additional transistor).
But the loads in question would be away from the Pi, and in 2 out of 4 (identified so far) cases running cables would be problematic - hard enough to become the biggest effort in the project, so it wouldn't happen.  And they're not in the same place, so I couldn't just move the Pi to the load.  Switching over WiFi seems ideal.  Bluetooth is marginal for range.
As this is an energy-efficiency project, I'm not going to do it if each receiver requires more than about a handful of Watts.  It should also be cheap - a Pi Zero W plus power supply, plus suitable casing for each load is starting to get a bit much. I'm looking for something home made or properly designed rather than one of those amazon-special relay boards that have a tendency relay boards to route mains traces right next to DC control lines.
This would seem to be a common problem, but there doesn't seem to be a common solution.  Any sort of compatible wireless GPIO solution device could provide the start for a solution.

I've used SonOff switches quite extensively, very reliable, you can reprogram with your own firmware (e.g. Tasmota) and have a local manual override button. They do require both live and neutral however.
Example Amazon Link

Thanks, I'll always have L&N present because the only time that's not the case would be lighting, and I don't want to automate lighting - it's not enough of a load to be worth it.  Their simplest/smallest/cheapest models seem compatible, which is good

Your question is a bit ambiguous (or perhaps I'm just thick), and it's also leaning toward being off-topic as a "shopping request".
But what I got from reading your Q was that you're looking for a relay that can be actuated over a wifi link. If that's the case, here's one item that might help. And if you want to do more research, here's a link to my search engine with the search term I used to find the Shelley unit.

Thanks, yes, I realised that it was possible to read it as a  shopping question despite aiming for "how do I do?" not "what do I buy?" - but knowing that an answer may revolve around a product.  The implied bit that (IMO) keeps it on topic is that a lot of wireless home automation stuff relies on a proprietary phone app while I need control from Python (or anything else I can run under Linux) - or even a hardware solution sending GPIO pin states wirelessly.

ShellyPy looks like the easy software solution, at a glance
